# name of Data-column in print-collection

Tags: qgis

How can I use the name of the data-column in a print-collection? (e.g. to use as headline)

I mean the column I choose at "layer properties" => Style => Graduated => column. I want to use it in legend or as headline.

Comment: Maybe a simple answer, but just type it manually?

Comment: Yes. Works. But I change the column often. The map, and the legend changes automaticly too. But when I changed it and saved it as PNG later I dont know what value (column) is in this PNG. I dont want to do it manually....

Comment: I do not quite understand why you would already use the print composer if your base data changes a lot? Do you need to make a lot of maps or not?

Comment: I want make maps from different columns and export it as PNG. But I need the legend too (and something to remind me of the used column)

Answer (score 1):

The name of the column you choose to categorise your data should appear in the legend just above the different categories (at last it does on qgis 2.18.13) if you insert two legend, you could use the second one to display your column name as a title by :

- 1 Deleting the legend Title (in legend main properties)
- 2 Deleting the layer name (in legend items properties)
- 3 unchecking  "resize to fit contents" (in legend main properties)
- 4 set the Item font to look as you like for a title
- 5 resizing the legend to only show the column name

Below are exemple of the same data categorise by the OBJECTID and the SHAPE_LEN fields with a second legend as a auto updating title.

[image]
[image]

Comment: OK, I'm using version 2.10. And I use TWO layers with a join. In this case, in there are inle the two layer-names in the legend, NOT the fieldname:
[Screens see here](https://picload.org/view/dgpdwigi/all.png.html).

Comment: PS: Tank you for your detailed answer!

Comment: With  2.18.13 even with a joint the legend display the symbology field name, it seem you need to upgrade